# Status 404, not found in SpringBoot with Microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I am having a problem please hope you can help me it seems that it does not recognize the user class.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-29T20:22:48.166+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/usuarios"
}
```

I am performing microservices, one is Zuul server, another is Eureka server and User service. Also I am trying to work the User class (which in a start was in the User service) in a different project as a library (users-commons), in which the User microservice would use it through dependency implementation in pom.xml, I did this because I will also need the User for later microservices so I decouple it.

Project where the user class is located, which will not be a project that runs an application, it will only be a library project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmv2Y.png)

Application.properties, from the Zuul microservice

```
spring.application.name = servicio-zuul-server
server.port = 8090

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone= http://localhost:8761/eureka

zuul.routes.usuarios.service-id=servicio-usuarios
zuul.routes.usuarios.path=/api/usuarios/**
```

In the User microservice

Uduario.Dao, I am using @RepositoryRestResource, to implement the full Crud automatically

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9txpF.png)

in: SpringbootServicioUsuariosApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"com.formacionbdi.springboot.app.usuarios.commons.models.entity"})
public class SpringbootServicioUsuariosApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootServicioUsuariosApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

in the pom.xml of servicio.usuario, the dependency of usuario.commons, which previously generated its jar

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.formacionbdi.springboot.app.usuarios.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>springboot-servicio-usuarios-commons</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am trying to run: localhost:8090/api/usuarios/usuarios, this is where I get the 404 error.

I have already done this same procedure in another project and I could do it without problems but in this case I don't understand what the problem is. Please hope you can help me.

Comment: please post the controller you are using in the user service

Comment: I am using @RepositoryRestResource, to implement the full Crud automatically with this it is not necessary to create class Service and Controller, I execute the GET, POST, PUT, DELETE through "usuarios" indicated in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is how I solved:
- First copy the package path that you have declared in your EntityScan and added it to the scanBasePackages attribute from @SpringBootApplication
- You can delete or comment the @EntityScan annotation.

So, it shoud end like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.formacionbdi.springboot.app.usuarios.commons.models.entity")
//@EntityScan({"com.formacionbdi.springboot.app.usuarios.commons.models.entity"})
```